# how the activemq server can known when to promote one slave to master?

Tags: jms, cluster-computing, activemq-classic

for ActiveMq, the sharing-nothing deployment is as following:

[image]

In a nutshell, when the master get down, one slave would be promoted as master. but I am not aware about:

1, who is responsible for determining whether the mater is down, for determining which slave should be promoted?  since the master itself has got down already.   is client responsible? and how?
2, which slave should be promoted as master? any one?

Answer (score 4):

For shared nothing (Pure Master Slave) setups,

A master connection is established from the slave to the master. This connection syncs the state of the master broker. If the network master (sync) connection from the slave to the master goes down, even for a short time, the slave broker will stop listening for replications and start it's own connectors (network and client connectors).

In the meanwhile, if the connection to the client also is broken (i.e. the master actually failed, crashed, hardware outtage, network down etc.), then the client will reconnect to the slave and continue there.

That is, if that has been configured in the client setup:
failover://(tcp://masterhost:61616,tcp://slavehost:61616)?randomize=false

This means a few things

- Only one slave can be attached to a master
- The slave is not "promoted" to master - it just operates as a standalone broker if the master goes down.
- If the master comes back online after a short outtage, it will keep operate as a stand alone broker side by side with the slave and the setup might become out of sync. The recovery is a bit painfull, and manual - i.e. shutting down each broker, manually copy the runtime data by file and restart them. Note that a Master broker that has failed will not reconnect to the slave and become the new slave automatically.

So, the  shared nothing state is useable mostly when the network connection between master and slave is extremly stable and the downtime of each node is very low (i.e. protection for hardware failure a few times a year or so).

I would use some other fail over approach if possible, shared disk, master+master etc.